# php mail function not working reply SMTP server response: 503

Tags: php, sendmail, phpmailer, email-client

I try to send mail using php mail function. but I getting error like:

```
PHP Warning:  mail(): SMTP server response: 503 This mail server requires authentication when attempting to send to a non-local e-mail address. Please check your mail client settings or contact your administrator to verify that the domain or address is defined for this server. in C:\Inetpub\vhosts\qubedns.co.in\httpdocs\Codes\design\rnp\mailsend.php on line 21
```

Here is my PHP SCRIPT:

```
<?php

$toEmail    = 'bikash336@gmail.com';
$subject    = 'hello';
$message    = 'Users are able to send emails to local domains and addresses but are unable to send email to any external address.';
$headers    = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers    .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
$headers    .= 'From: <sales@leonwallet.com>' . "\r\n";

$Status = mail($toEmail,$subject,$message,$headers);

if($Status){
    echo '1';
}else{
    echo '0';
}

?>
```

Here is my Server configuration: http://qubedns.co.in/codes/php/

What's wrong with me?

Comment: configure smtp with email and password, if you are not using local email address

Comment: Don't tag your question with PHPMailer if you're not using [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer), but If you don't know what you're doing with `mail()`, you should be!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution with PHPMailer.
Its work for me.

```
<?php
require('mailserver/PHPMailerAutoload.php');
require('mailserver/class.phpmailer.php');
require('mailserver/class.smtp.php');
require('mailserver/class.pop3.php');

$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->CharSet="UTF-8";
$mail->Debugoutput = 'html';
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$mail->Port = 465;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->Username = 'sales@leonwallet.com';
$mail->Password = 'password';
$mail->From = 'sales@leonwallet.com';
$mail->FromName = 'Leon Sales Team';
$mail->AddAddress($to);
$mail->AddReplyTo('sales@leonwallet.com', 'Leon Sales Team');
$mail->Subject = $sub;
$mail->AltBody = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!";
$mail->Body = $message;
if(!$mail->Send()){
  echo "1"; // ERROR
}else{
  echo "0"; // SUCCESS
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution. For me he solved the problem

When I changed the environment, the TO parameter was configured with the domain of my test / development project.
I changed the TO email to the production email and the error disappeared.

Here is the solution: http://www.marathon-studios.com/blog/php-mail-503-error/